# HTML file name having garbage characters

Tags: html, dropbox

I have been shared a link of a html file. `user_profile.html` from dropbox.

To naked eye the file name seems to be user_profile.html but in editor `user_profile<200f>.html`.

In dropbox folder the file appending those charaters in file url.

```
file:///home/mohan/Dropbox/User/management/retain_classes%E2%80%8F.html.
```

What could be the possible issue?

Comment: this is not funk values it is some automatic converted values

Answer (score 0):

`U+200F`, or `E2 80 8F` is an invisible unicode character called [“right-to-left mark”](http://unicode.org/reports/tr9/), or “rtl mark”. It is used to change text direction within a text, to be able to mix a language written right to left, with a language written left to right.

**Usage example:**

```
<code>Stack Overflow is called &rlm;سرریز پشته&lrm; in Arabic</code>
```

gives:

`Stack Overflow is called ‏سرریز پشته‎ in Arabic`

Even though you can't see the character, you should be able to rename the file and delete the rtl mark (rename the file and try moving the cursor left and right with the keyboard arrows. You will see how the cursor stops for an extra, zero width character).

Also, I'm flagging this as off topic, as it has nothing to do with programming.